# Salvar um JSON no banco vs Relacionamento?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Quando não sabia muito sobre a questão de estrutura de banco de dados e relacionamento entre tabelas, costumava utilizar JSON  ou então dados separados por vírgula num determinado campo de uma tabela qualquer  no banco.

Na verdade, lembro-me de um caso específico onde eu precisava relacionar várias imagens com uma determinada postagem. Essas imagens eu salvava uma lista em `JSON` num determinado campo chamado `imagens`.

A estrutura era mais ou menos assim

```
-----------------------------------------------
tabela
-----------------------------------------------
id | imagens                      | usuario_id
-----------------------------------------------
1  | ["image1.png", "image2.png"] |   55
2  | NULL                         |   56
```

Porém, em um determinado momento onde começaram a surgir mudanças nesse sistema, fui duramente criticado por um programador que sabia mais de banco de dados do que eu (e foi zoado também) por ter feito assim.

Ele me explicou que os dados deveriam ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
--------------------------
tabela
--------------------------
id | usuario_id
--------------------------
1  |  55
2  |  56


----------------------------
imagens
----------------------------
post_id | url_imagem
 1      | image1.png
 1      | image2.png
```

Considerando esses dois casos (relacionamento VS serialização salva em um campo), podemos afirmar que, estruturalmente falando, usar o `JSON` é uma má prática?

Fui criticado por usar dados em `JSON` num campo de uma tabela ao invés de relacionamento, mas existe algum caso onde eu devo/posso utilizar uma serialização e salvá-la num campo do banco de dados, sem que isso seja considerado uma má prática de programação?

Comment: Acredito que se você tiver dados não relacionados que possam ser salvos em um banco, como configurações personalizadas de um usuário por exemplo, você possa salar sim em `json` a menos que você vá precisar de detalhes sobre essa atualização.

Comment: Usando o primeiro exemplo que você postou seria possível definir data e hora da inclusão de cada uma das imagens? Isso pode ser uma informação importante para alguns sistemas, mas se estes detalhes não fizerem diferença para estes dados salvos, não vejo mal em salvar `json`

Comment: Pois é, o problema é que o meu chefe depois falou em fazer "album de fotos" com essas imagens. Então teria que ter a data da imagem sim :(. Essas implementações futuras detonam o código e a estrutura do banco!

Comment: Pronto, no fim das contas depende de como esses dados serão usados. Se eu salvo por exemplo um `json` com as configurações de tema para um sistema feitas por um usuário e eu só preciso saber como é a configuração final da alteração,pode não ser interessante salvar cada dado dessa configuração em uma tupla, poruqe serão muitas tuplas de cada um dos muitos usuários e salvar um `json` por usiário pode facilitar muita coisa.

Comment: Sendo assim, só é má prática se a estrutura criada prejudicar o desempenho ou o desenvolvimento da sua solução.

Comment: Eu discordo no sentido que a evolução do esquema do BD é uma coisa chata, sim, mas necessária: tentar fugir dela usando "atalhos" tem uma boa chance de trazer dor-de-cabeça depois... Uma exceção é quando os dados "variáveis" não vão ser usados no banco de jeito nenhum, e não tem muita previsão de que estrutura eles vão ter. Um exemplo real que ocorreu num sistema meu são as *preferências da Interface de Usuário* - cada usuário tem seu JSON com suas preferências, e sempre que a IU muda o conjunto de preferências pode mudar. Mas como nada disso tem relação nenhuma com o BD, um JSON é suficiente.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Um banco de dados relacional, normalizado, assume que cada atributo (valor de uma coluna numa tabela) seja **atômico**, ou seja, não possa ser quebrado em pedaços menores do ponto de vista do modelo relacional. *Do ponto de vista do modelo relacional*, é bom frisar: ninguém sugeriria que você guardasse cada dígito de um número numa coluna separada, ou cada caractere de uma string. Se um dado não é usado para formar relações entre tabelas, esse dado pode ser considerado para todos efeitos atômico.

No seu exemplo acima isso não é necessariamente verdade: você tem uma lista de imagens, ok, mas essa lista de imagens pode ser considerada atômica? Cada imagem pertence a uma única linha da tabela, não há sobreposição de imagens (i.e. a mesma imagem pertencer a vários *posts* distintos), você sempre vai estar interessado na lista completa e mais nada (i.e. não é possível que você resolva, por exemplo, pegar só a primeira imagem da lista, para fazer uma miniatura ou imagem de capa por exemplo)?

Se a resposta for um "sim" definitivo, não tem a menor chance de você querer *partes* dessa lista de imagens pra qualquer coisa, ou é a lista inteira ou não é nada, então não, não é má prática armazenar a lista dessa forma, seja usando JSON, strings separadas por vírgula, [Blobs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOB), etc. Da mesma forma que sua imagem está num arquivo externo, e esse arquivo é visto pelo modelo relacional como uma coisa atômica (você não referencia "pedaços" dessa imagem no seu modelo, somente a imagem inteira), a lista de imagens - ou mesmo alguma coisa mais complexa e estruturada - pode sim ser vista como uma entidade atômica, e portanto salva em um único atributo.

Entretanto, na grande maioria das vezes a resposta não é um "sim": é perfeitamente possível conceber casos de uso em que uma imagem seja compartilhada por mais de um *post*, ou que você queira recuperar só um subconjunto das imagens do *post* para qualquer coisa, ou mesmo que você queira associar a cada imagem meta-dados adicionais (como o tipo, tamanho, data de criação, etc). Nesse caso, uma representação [**normalizada**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) costuma ser ideal, e essa sugestão alternativa apresentada corresponderia a uma forma normal.

Via de regra, eu diria pra, na dúvida, adotar a forma normalizada: é mais fácil desnormalizar uma tabela depois (caso surjam problemas de desempenho, por exemplo) do que normalizar uma que começou desnormalizada. A menos que você tenha bons motivos pra salvar um JSON numa tabela evite fazer isso. Há casos que um JSON é sim a melhor representação para um conjunto de dados, mas nesse caso um banco de dados não relacional - comumente referido como [NoSQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) - pode ser uma opção preferível.

Comment: Muito bom @mgibsonbr. Interessante é que, caso precisasse ordenar as imagens por tamanho (como precisei de fazer), teria que fazer uma gambiarra enorme no caso do JSON. Creio que nesse caso realmente a melhor solução seria aplicar o "sim"

Comment: Acho que você quer dizer "aplicar o não", não? De todo modo, o que você quis dizer com "ordenar por tamanho"? É necessário que as imagens sejam **armazenadas** no BD por ordem de tamanho? Ou uma consulta em particular tem de trazê-las nessa ordem? (e outra consulta poder querer em ordem alfabética, por exemplo) Para conjuntos pequenos, ordenar não é nenhum drama, mas esse é um exemplo perfeito de tarefa que o BD *poderia* fazer por você se o modelo estiver normalizado, mas você teria de fazer à mão na camada de aplicação se ele não estiver.

Comment: É verdade, é o "não". No caso, para ordenar pelo tamanho, seria melhor salvar numa tabela de imagens relacionada ao post, com o seu respectivo tamanho. Melhor do que ficar usando o PHP, `json_decode` e ainda ter que descobrir o tamanho da imagem com `filesize` para depois ter que fazer um `sort` no `array`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, falando em JSON, BD relacional e não relacional, me lembrei deste [artigo](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/marc-linster/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-new-developer-reality).

Comment: @TobyMosque Caramba! Muito bom você ter passado esse artigo, eu estava em vias de utilizar MongoDB em um projeto futuro lado a lado com o Postgres, mas pelo jeito é mais negócio estudar essas funcionalidades novas do Postgres e manter tudo num banco só. Vou ver isso com mais cuidado. Valeu!

Comment: @mgibsonbr, apenas verifique se a versão do PostgreSQL é pelo menos a 9.3, apesar que o ideal é usar pelo menos a 9.4. Então a versão do PostgreSQL pode ser um impedimento para você.